# Jquery Script Error on ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this 2 codes returning "script error alert" to me on Internet Explorer 8. What is wrong please (or missing)?

```
<script>
 $(".alert").alert('close');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict()

    $j(function(){
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
    $j(window).load(function(){
        $j('.flexslider').flexslider({
           animation: "slide",
            start: function(slider){
               $('body').removeClass('loading');
            }
        }); 
    });
 </script>
```

The second I know that is because of this (but I dont know why?):

```
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
```

and this:

```
$('body').removeClass('loading');
```

Comment: $(".alert").alert('close'); what's that..? What are you trying to do ..?

Comment: what is SyntaxHighlighter.all(); ? and where it is defined?

Comment: [How to troubleshoot script errors in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308260)

Comment: That is to inicialize flexslider, and the alert is a jquery from bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SyntaxHighlighter.all();` is causing a problem then you've probably forgotten to load the JavaScript that defines `SyntaxHighlighter` or perhaps the case is different than you're trying to use.

This:

```
$('body').removeClass('loading');
```

will be a problem because you've called [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and that will return `$` to whatever it was before jQuery tried to take it over. You should use the `$j` that `noConflict` gave you:

```
$j('body').removeClass('loading');
```

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure if this is the issue but you don't have a semi-colon at the end of the following line:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict()
```

Comment: Semicolon terminators are actually mostly optional in JavaScript. Leaving them out usually isn't a great idea but you don't need them for the most part.